# Prevent location change in browser url in VueJs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I have a vuejs application where i make rest api calls to the backend. I have define the router and navigate the different components. Now as I navigate i see the https://domain-name.com/#/abc the route path in the browser URL. I want to prevent this so that it always show https://domain-name.com/ irrespective of what path i traverse. Is there a way to do it in Vuejs or any other solution. Appreciate you help!

Thanks,
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

You're using Vue Router, the idea of it to change routes...

Since you've got the Hash in the url under your router you'll need to add `mode` attribute.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

This will remove the /#/someRoute and it will become /someRoute

Once adding history mode, you'll need to setup your apache/nginx server up respectively to reflect if the user was to type in domain.com/someRoute they would receive nothing which we can fix [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations).

If you want the link to permanently stay as www.domain.com instead of using vue-router, you'll have to change components as and when you need them essentially having a million and one if statements on the page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For removing the /#/ i have already used the history mode, but i need the path to be www.domain.com always. I wanted to do it in a clean way. I know in Angular we can do it by setting  skipLocationChange to true. Thought there will be something similar in Vue as well. But looks like it is quite difficult in Vue to achieve

Comment: Does using `mode: 'abstract'` give you the desired outcome?

Comment: With mode: ''abstract' the home itself is not loading, i get a blank page.

Comment: I think the issue is you're using a library that was specifically designed for routing to go directly against it's rules. You'll need to create parameters to say which component  you need loading at any given point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [alias](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html#alias)

> An alias of /a as /b means when the user visits /b, the URL remains
>   /b, but it will be matched as if the user is visiting /a.

The above can be expressed in the route configuration as:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/a', component: A, alias: '/b' }
  ]
})
```

So, in your case

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
  // the URL will remains https://domain-name.com/
    { path: '/abc', component: ABC, alias: '/' }
    { path: '/def', component: DEF, alias: '/' }
  ]
})
```