# VueJS Router prevent back on certains router-link's

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Building PWA app with VueJS and I have tabs like navigation component. But instead of show/hide content, navigation is done through Vue Router. Side effect of this navigation is "back" button behavior, every navigation action is logged in browser history, after I visit 4 tabs, and if I want to go back to actual page which was before page with tabs, I need to press "back" 4 or more times (depends on how many times I navigated trough tabs).

What I want to do is something like this:

```
<router-link no-history="true" to="tab1">Tab1</router-link>
<router-link no-history="true" to="tab2">Tab2</router-link>
<router-link no-history="true" to="tab3">Tab3</router-link>
```

Of course, I don't want to do it globally. If this even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50621920/prevent-location-change-in-browser-url-in-vuejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You need to use `router.replace`.

*From Vue Documentation :*

> It acts like router.push, the only difference is that it navigates without pushing a new history entry, as its name suggests - it replaces the current entry.

In your case, you would just need to add the `replace` attribute to your `router-link` tag :

`<router-link to="tab3" replace>Tab3</router-link>`

You can find more informations about `replace` on [Vue programmatic navigation doc](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-replace-location-oncomplete-onabort)

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed what I'm looking for. I will approve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

add `replace` to your `router-link` to avoid stacking routes on the navigation history :

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }


const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]


const router = new VueRouter({
  routes 
})


const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h5>Navigate between routes then click "previous"</h5>
  <button @click="$router.go(-1)">Previous</button>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/foo" replace>Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar" replace>Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```